# how to make combo box html to behave like slide horizontally with next and previous link (using jquery?)

Tags: jquery, html

I want this to be looked something like in the image in the following link.
http://niman.com.np/slide.jpg

```html
<select name="service" id="service">
        <option value="55">One</option>
        <option value="57">Three</option>
        <option value="56">Two</option>
</select>
```